# How to initialize InMobi with MoPub? #withAdditionalNetwork

Tags: mopub, inmobi

We used InMobi and switched to MoPub. InMobi is still supported with mediation by MoPub. InMobi provided a guide how to integrate this (https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/mediation-guidelines/mopub/android-mopub-guidelines). I followed the guide closely but unable to retrieve requests and impressions in InMobi. As I can see from the MoPubSDK I think I need to bind the InMobi to MoPub with #withAdditionalNetwork.

Answer (score 2):

The most important step isn't very emphasised. It is

**Step 3.2: Add the Custom Event**

Add the custom events to your MoPub project. The custom events for different ad formats are also available as part of the sample code available [here](https://dl.inmobi.com/SDK/Adapters/MoPubMediation_CE_InMobi_Android_SDK.zip). The custom events are available under the relevant package structure. The code also has sample activities to illustrate how to mediate via MoPub SDK.

The content needed from the above linked archive is the following:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Copy this to your Android project. Then alter the MoPubSDK initialization process like this

```
SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("362da1882dfc49f3a33b92ea1708f3a5")
            .withAdditionalNetwork(InMobiAdapterConfiguration.class.getName())
            .build();

MoPub.initializeSdk(activity, sdkConfiguration, initSdkListener());
```